# Why are people trying to surf to example.com/{{link}}?

Tags: google-analytics, url

I’ve noticed in Google Analytics accessed URLs such as `example.com/{{link}}`.

Is this like an hacking attempt or is there some simple explanation that made some reach such a weird link? Either way, I would love an explanation.

Comment: Without more information, I would venture to guess that someone has used their CMS/Blogging software to create a link that has failed and other bots are following these links. {{something}} is often used as a variable within CMS/Blogging software. There are other possibilities. But that is just my initial take on things. I think it would depend upon log file patterns for further clues.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely an attempt to spam your logs/analytics. Many websites accidentally leave their logs and/or analytics publicly available and as a result crawlers index their contents. Since many log and analytic software turn URLs into hyperlinks these links are valid and can count as backlinks to a site if found by the search engines.

Their value is questionable at best buy as far as spammers go, it's automated and simple to do so why not do it?

If you're looking for an actionable item, just make sure your logs and analytics cannot be viewed in a browser (at least without authentication first).

Comment: I'm actually now seeing these in many google search results. Any idea? How can I resolve?